# I want to include response and logging of response at server side for swagger server using JAXRS

Tags: jax-rs, swagger, slf4j, swagger-codegen

I am using swagger spec for server side code generation using swagger-codegen and JAXRS.

Now I want to get a set of sample inputs as json file for my APIs and respond with those when I hit my APIs by reading the values.
Also I want to log these responses on the server prompt using slf4j.

Can somebody point me any reference?

Comment: Do you have a more specific question in mind, or are you just looking for a beginners tutorial in using these tools?

Comment: Tom, I have used the swagger-codegen for generating server side code. Now I just want to modify the server side code generation technique with customized input and response instead of the default. So this is my required scenario.

Comment: @Jayant , you will need to be more specific for anyone to help you in this community. Please paste some code and your exact requirement.

Comment: Currently my response is just some static messages. I want dynamic responses as defined in a json file. Lets say I have a defined json output file is test.json, when I host the service and request the API, I will get the response in the same format as defined by json file.